# may vs might, same or different

Tags: modal-verbs

Do the following sentences have the same meaning?

a) You need to discuss with them how they ***may*** help you.

b) You need to discuss with them how they ***might*** help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would take a hard-core stickler to recommend one over the other.

Yes, the two words mean different things. That's why there are two of them. But in this case, both examples would be understood the same way.

There are subtleties. *May* could suggest that they need *permission* to help you. May they? Let's hope so.

*Might* leans toward a question of probability. Strictly speaking, you don't want to find out how they *might* help. You want to find out how they *will* help.

But that's splitting frog hairs. For purposes of ordinary conversation, either one will do just fine.

Comment: It's not really that they mean different things -- they're both just basic possibility modals -- as much as it is that they're used in different idioms and constructions, their epistemic and deontic senses don't work the same ways, and they contract differently (_mightn't_ but not *_mayn't_). For example. There are lots of differences; they're two different verbs now, with different lives.

Comment: @JohnLawler So, from what you seem to say, qualifying a research for differences between those two verbs  as an "exercice in splitting  frog hairs" wouldn't be very proper?

Comment: No, it could go on forever. There are so many differences, in so many contexts, and interactions with so many other words, that it would be an exercise in classifying beetles

Comment: In the original sentence, what is the difference between "how they 'will' help you" and "how they 'might' help you"?